# transfer file from PC to android programmatically

Tags: android, file, sockets

I managed to establish a  connection between my PC and device both by Bluetooth and by IP address thru the socket mechanism. I also was able to transfer values (int, String etc) to the PC. Now I need to transfer a file from my PC to computer. Is this possible ?How can I do this?

Here is how I transferred values to the PC. I need to transfer a file from PC to the android device.

Client:

```
                 DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                 outToServer.writeInt(mMove);
```

Server:

```
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                  int str = in.readInt();
```

Comment: if you were able to pass values then you've basically got the starting points for passing a file.  Read the file in as bytes and send those bytes to the destination device (be it pc or droid).  Ensure you always receive a response letting you know that the bytes were received.  Rinse/repeat until the entire file has been consumed  and sent to the destination.

Comment: thanks do you know where i can get an example for this?